# Moving data from one GKE PV to another

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

We have data stored on a persistent volume attached to a k8s pod on google cloud. And we want to copy these data over to another persistent volume attached to a different pod on the same cluster.

Is there any direct way to do this? We don't want to leverage other storage as an intermediate though.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the data so that both pods have the same data or are you really just trying to move the data to a different pod?

Comment: Maybe this [doc (Using preexisting persistent disks as PersistentVolumes)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd) will be of assistance.

Comment: @GariSingh To copy the data as I want data on both pods not just one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [velero](https://velero.io/) to move the **PV** and **PVC** across the **cluster**

for that,[enter link description here](https://velero.io/) you can use the tool velero

which will **snapshot** the disk clone the data and create the new PV and PVC for you

You can use this article for reference : https://faun.pub/clone-migrate-data-between-kubernetes-clusters-with-velero-e298196ec3d8

You need to create the Bucket and service account

Bucket will be used to store the state and service account for access purpose

Velero can be used across different cloud provider also

you can use the existing GCP plugin and using that migrate PV or PVC or any resource of the Kubernetes

Velero install example :

```
velero install --provider gcp --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.0.0 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --secret-file SECRET-FILENAME
```